TypefaceSpan within TypefaceSpan is not working
I want to set text with differnt typeface.
 stringBuilder.setSpan(new TypefaceSpan(typeface1),10,100,Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
 stringBuilder.setSpan(new TypefaceSpan(typeface2),20,30,Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

But only typeFace1 is shown. typeface2 is not working.
How can I get the desired result.

Have three separate ranges, without overlaps:
stringBuilder.setSpan(new TypefaceSpan(typeface1),10,20,Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
stringBuilder.setSpan(new TypefaceSpan(typeface2),20,30,Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
stringBuilder.setSpan(new TypefaceSpan(typeface1),30,100,Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

